Android Crash: Binary XML file line : Error inflating class
I have a very frustrating error that I cannot explain.
I am getting the Following error. I don't know what this means and i couldn't figure anything else out
I have also mentioned the MainActivity.kt code and Build.Gradle and activity_main.xml code as well.
If you can please also explain what this is and what i can make sure of to avoid this in future
Error:
Process: com.abhay.expensetracker, PID: 27787
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abhay.expensetracker/com.abhay.expensetracker.view.main.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in com.abhay.expensetracker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #31 in com.abhay.expensetracker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in com.abhay.expensetracker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #31 in com.abhay.expensetracker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31 in com.abhay.expensetracker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.abhay.expensetracker.view.base.BaseFragment.getBinding(.kt:16)
at com.abhay.expensetracker.view.dashboard.DashboardFragment.setupRV(DashboardFragment.kt:86)
at com.abhay.expensetracker.view.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreate(DashboardFragment.kt:49)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3099)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2164)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2065)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3267)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3166)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1974)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:163)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3099)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2164)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2065)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.kt:162)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:53)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:247)
2024-08-04 17:06:21.608 27787-27787 AndroidRuntime          com.abhay.expensetracker             E      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:226) (Ask Gemini)at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at com.abhay.expensetracker.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:60)
at com.abhay.expensetracker.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:54)
at com.abhay.expensetracker.view.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:35)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    @Inject
    lateinit var repo: TransactionRepo

    private val viewModel: TransactionViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        viewModel

        initViews(binding)
        observeNavElements(binding, navHostFragment.navController)

    }

    private fun initViews(binding: ActivityMainBinding) {
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?
            ?: return

        with(navHostFragment.navController) {
            appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(graph)
            setupActionBarWithNavController(this, appBarConfiguration)
        }
    }

    private fun observeNavElements(
        binding: ActivityMainBinding,
        navController: NavController
    ) {
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {

                R.id.dashboardFragment -> {
                    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
                }
                R.id.addTransactionFragment -> {
                    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
                    binding.toolbar.title = getString(R.string.text_add_transaction)
                }
                else -> {
                    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        navHostFragment.navController.navigateUp()
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
        <!--        android:backgroundTint="@color/surface"-->

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


build.gradle

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.abhay.expensetracker"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.abhay.expensetracker"
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    // Room
    val room_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.7.3")

    // Navigation Components
    val nav_version = "2.7.7"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.8.2")


    // Lottie Animation Library
    implementation("com.airbnb.android:lottie:4.2.0")

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46")


}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}


I have tried adding dependencies that people siad would fix it, i have tried finding a fix online but no luck.
